# Не могу подключится клиентом dbForge к базе данных

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Ошибка вот такая:

> Server does not support diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 for keyexchange

на сервере Ubuntu 15.
По SSH захожу без проблем, обычным клиентом. А это пробую DBforge.

Comment: вы подключаетесь mysql-клиентом, запущенном на одной машине, к mysql-серверу, запущенному на другой? какой протокол используете? tcp/ip?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в общем тех поддержка меня отправила сюда http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=31944, Mysql worckbench  тоже отказался подключаться. Я правда не особо понял что там написано файл на сервере нашел а вот что менять не понимаю

Comment: менять там предлагается содержимое файла `sshd_config`. предполагаю, что речь о файле `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это вот как раз я и понял только дальше нифига =)

Comment: *As a workaround, you can specify the following in the sshd_config file and restart sshd* — мой вольный перевод: *в качестве обходного средства вы можете указать следующее в файле `sshd_config` и перезапустить `sshd`*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin мой вольный перевод это поменять параметр Protocol 2 на Protocol 1 но не помогло =)

Comment: вообще-то я вижу по приведённой вами ссылке строку, которую и предлагают добавить в файл `sshd_config`. вроде бы, в этой строке нет упоминаний слова *protocol*.

Comment: В общем мне надоело танцевать с бубном я поставил 14 ubuntu  и все работает

Answer (score 1):

как написано по приведённой ссылке, можно в качестве обходного пути добавить в файл `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` строку:

```
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

и, проверив синтаксис конфигурационного файла (если ничего не выдаст в ответ, то синтаксис верен):

```
$ sudo sshd -t
```

перезагрузить конфигурацию:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/ssh reload
```

---

но в самом конце по приведённой ссылке есть сообщение от 2016/02/06, что новая версия *dbforge* уже не содержит описанной ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

запиши

```
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
Ciphers 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr
```

в файл

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

потом рестартани sshd

```
service ssh restart
service sshd restart
```